# How to send an image to the backend server that is using Flask in Python

Tags: python, flask, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I have a simple backend server script that uses Flask to accept HTTP requests.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from object_detector import ObjectDetector
import skimage

skimage.imsave(file_path, request.args.get("image_data"))
res = od.detect_object(file_path) #ignore this, I am just passing 
                                   the file name to another python 
                                   script
return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='10.0.10.15')
```

From the front end, I have a simple script to send the image data (which I think is incorrect).

```
import requests
import ast
from skimage.io import imread

with open("my_image.JPEG", 
          "rb") as image_file:
img = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())

parameters = {'image_data': img}

ret = requests.get("http://10.0.10.15:5000/get_bounding_box", 
                   params=parameters)
```

Now, I need to learn what is the right way to send the image data to the backend. I don't think I am doing it correctly because at the backend when I am saving the received data as an image back again at the server side it throws an error.

here is the error`

```
File "/home/cvuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/cvuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/cvuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/cvuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/cvuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/cvuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/cvuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/cvuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/mnt/data2/abhishek/singleshotdetection/server_detection.py", line 14, in hello
    skimage.io.imsave(file_path, request.args.get("image_data"))
  File "/home/cvuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/io/_io.py", line 158, in imsave
    if is_low_contrast(arr):
  File "/home/cvuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/exposure/exposure.py", line 513, in is_low_contrast
    dlimits = dtype_limits(image)
  File "/home/cvuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/util/dtype.py", line 44, in dtype_limits
    imin, imax = dtype_range[image.dtype.type]
KeyError: <type 'numpy.unicode_'>`
```

Comment: what's the error? You probably want to change it to `POST` the image data rather than trying to pass it through a `GET` parameter

Comment: @Cfreak I just pasted the error in the question. Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with `skimage` but from that error it looks like `imread` turns your data into a python object you can make operations on. You aren't going to be able to send that because it's data as well as code. You might be able to use `pickle`, or see if your `skimage` object has a way to output the raw data.  Either way I recommend using `POST` instead of `GET` to send that much data over an HTTP request.

Comment: @Cfreak thanks. I even tried just reading the binary data from the file and encoding it as base64 as edited in the question now. I decode it back as well at the server side.

Comment: @Cfreak I got it finally working. I ditched skimage and did it using simple base64 encoding and decoding. Regarding using POST instead of GET, do you know on the server side how do I read the argument values if I use POST from the client's side?